# Stored procedure to sort one row with other rows places

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add this to a parameterized stored procedure. I have code to sort it like that but it is just a select statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[CountryRegion]
ORDER BY
    CASE CountryRegionCode
         WHEN 'GB' THEN '1' 
         WHEN 'BR' THEN '2'
         ELSE Name
    END
GO
```

In these pictures everything could be clear what I would like to happen. Before and after sort. Thanks!

[image: Before image sort.]

[image: After result sort.]

Comment: If it works, why do you need a stored procedure?

Comment: Cause I would like for user input the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedureName @RegionCode nvarchar(2)
    AS
    SELECT *
    FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[CountryRegion]
    WHERE CountryRegionCode = @RegionCode
    UNION ALL
       SELECT *
    FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[CountryRegion]
    WHERE CountryRegionCode = @RegionCode
    --Any order by you need
    END
    GO
```

And call it using :

```
EXEC yourProcedureName @RegionCode = 'GB'
```

Comment: But if I would like to put the record to any other place by row ? For example 60 ?

Comment: @RaimondsPlume: it gets messy quickly. Do you want each row to be in the same custom order all the time? Or a different custom order eachtime?

Comment: Different custom order eachtime. If i need the row 40 to put to row 70 like changing two records...

Comment: @RaimondsPlume My answer is from what I understood from your example. If you want a suitable one consider giving more scenarios of your desired result where we can see more of your conditions.

Comment: That was right but i wanted a little bit different result. Thank you. I have found the correct thing at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

I would use this personally. to sort by name *after* the preference sort

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProcedureName 
   @RegionCode nvarchar(2)
AS
--your select
     ORDER BY
         CASE CountryRegionCode
             WHEN @RegionCode THEN 1
             ELSE 2
         END,
         Name
```

Comment: Yes it shows the same result but i would like to see Stored Procedure with user input. Example: There are 200 countries, Country with row number 120 i want to put at the top of table that it now is number 1. And the number one which was now is 120.

Answer (score 0):

This was the result what I needed and what worked to replace one record under the specified parameter record.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE something
@CountryRegionCode nvarchar(3),
@Name nvarchar(50)

AS
SELECT Name,CountryRegionCode,ModifiedDate FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[CountryRegion]
     ORDER BY
     CASE CountryRegionCode
     WHEN @CountryRegionCode THEN @Name
     ELSE Name
     END
```